# hibernate select all projections group by

Tags: java, hibernate

In hibernate Criteria specification, if I want to group property in table, I must use Projections.groupProperty.  The problem is I can't select all the field in the table.

What I want to is:

SELECT * FROM entity GROUP BY field

If i use group in hibernate Criteria, then the groupProperty must be exist, and the sql result will be:
SELECT field FROM entity GROUP BY field.

Is there any way to get what I want?  I see in hibernate code, in CriteriaJoinWalker, when I want to select all (select *), the code is already specify if there is projection or not.  My assumption if I want to change the behavior, I must change the CriteriaJoinWalker code.  I can modify the code, and maybe I can get the result what I want, but if I can, I do not want to override the hibernate core code to my project.  Is there any way to change it directly without change hibernate code?

```
    // CriteriaJoinWalker
    if(translator.hasProjection())
    {
        resultTypes = translator.getProjectedTypes();
        initProjection(translator.getSelect(), translator.getWhereCondition(), translator.getOrderBy(), translator.getGroupBy(), LockMode.NONE);
    } else
    {
        resultTypes = (new Type[] {
            TypeFactory.manyToOne(persister.getEntityName())
        });
        initAll(translator.getWhereCondition(), translator.getOrderBy(), LockMode.NONE);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use Projections then you will not be able to get an Entity object as a whole. Unfortunately hibernate cant help you. Check out this [Issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1615) and also check out this [thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=959692).

Comment: Yeah, I know... As I said before. Seems like there is no way to get entity from Projections.