# select "all columns" with "group by" in hibernate criteria queries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, group-by, hibernate-criteria

I want to write a criteria query using "group by" and want to return all the columns.

Plane sql is like this:

```
select * from Tab group by client_name order by creation_time;
```

I understand that it will have `count(distinct client_name)` number of rows.

My current query which doesn't seem to give proper result is as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession(requestType).createCriteria(Tab.class);
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("client_name")));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("creationTime"));
```

This query returns `"client_name"` only. I don't want to manually put all column names. There must be some way, what could be done?

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678216/hibernate-select-all-projections-group-by

Comment: in mysql is not permitted, click here for explanation
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243344/group-by-de-mysql-obliga-a-meter-todos-los-campos-del-select

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding something.  If you `GROUP BY` in SQL, then you need to group by all selected columns.  The same applies to Hibernate - if you `groupProperty` in a `Projection`, you're telling Hibernate that that column is a group column.  If no other columns/fields are referenced, Hibernate will assume you don't want them, as they would also need to be grouped.

To take a step back: what are you trying to do?  If you have duplicate data across *all* columns in a table, you might have bad data, or be persisting data incorrectly.  At the very least, your key would be messed up.

Answer (score 0):

In hibernate for projections, all columns required needs to be added to projection list. To get the result in entity we have to use setResultTransformer. Check below example to get group by in hibernate:

```
 ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("column1"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("column2"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("column3"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Table.class));
```

Answer (score 0):

when using hibernate projection you should add all columns which are needed in projection list. you have only used Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("client_name"))

this . so it is clear that return only client_name.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get all columns of the database by using a group based on a single column. Instead, you can use all columns in the **group by clause** and in the **select** as well which you want. To get the result in hibernate like below

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession(requestType).createCriteria(Tab.class);
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("client_name"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("column2"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("column3"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("client_name"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("column2"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("column3"));
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("creationTime"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by assigning the entity class and property names after which filtering them dynamically as done below :

```
Criteria criteria = getSession(requestType).createCriteria(Tab.class);
    
    Class<?> entityClass = Tab.class;
    String[] propertyNames = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityClass).getPropertyNames();
    
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("client_name")));
    
    //skipping client_name as already added first
    for (String propertyName : propertyNames) {
        if (!"client_name".equals(propertyName)) {
            criteria.add(Projections.groupProperty(propertyName));
        }
    }
    
    // Add order by if needed
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("creationTime"));
    
    List<Object[]> result = criteria.list();
```