# Hibernate group by of a parent class/domain

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

My models are as follows

```
class A{
   int id;
   String name;
}

class B{
   int id;
   String name;
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   A a;
}

class C{
   int id;
   int name;
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   B b;
}
```

Now I want to get the result from table/class C group by class A

I have written so far

```
Criteria criteria = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
                C.class);
criteria. (Group by A); // i dont know how to do it

return criteria.list();
```

I don't know how to put the group by Class A

So how to do this??

Comment: you could also use a hibernate query and then group by ? from className where condition group by classNameA

Comment: could you please write me the code?

Comment: hey please visit this[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997675/select-all-columns-with-group-by-in-hibernate-criteria-queries], check how the criteria query is used, and then try urs

Comment: and just like some threads say without projections you cannot get a whole entity in a criteria query, use sql in hibernate, in that case, you could use the group by like in every sql query